# How to insert more than 10^6 elements in a array

Tags: c

I want to operate on 10^9 elements. For this they should be stored somewhere but in c, it seems that an array can only store 10^6 elements. So is there any way to operate on such a large number of elements in c?

The error thrown is `error: size of array ‘arr’ is too large"`.

Comment: Is it possible to tell us what kind of variablet type you are going to use? Anyway, have you tried to do the work by seperating the data in 2 arrays?

Comment: Can u suggest me which database to use with c.It would be helpful if u provide me the Link???

Comment: I Have to store integers element.But what will be use of using 2 arrays I have to store 10^9 elements and then operate on them.Using two arrays will store only 2*10^6 elements!!!!

Comment: There is no such limitation in C. It is in your compiler/platform.

Comment: For large arrays you have to use `malloc` (see the answers below). But make sure you don't use up your RAM! If you allocate 10^9 `int`s, you are asking for 4GB of RAM, which in 32bit computers you basically don't have (knowing that some of the RAM is already taken at least by the operating system)

Comment: I hope you're using a 64 bit OS and that you have plenty of RAM (> 4 GB).

Comment: Please give more details, about your platform, your compiler, the source line this error is coming from, is this a compile time error or occurs at run time...

Comment: @Shahbaz:  Using `malloc` is not the only solution, the array can be allocated `static` also.

Comment: @Clifford, I never looked into how the global/static memory is initialized, but I always assumed there is some sort of hidden automatic `malloc` behind it. Do you know anything about that? I had known, by experience that you can take large memory as a global variable.

Comment: @Shahbaz: It depends on the runtime environment rather than the language definition.  You are right in the sense that in a desktop OS, the OS loader will provide the process with sufficient memory to satisfy its static memory and stack requirements on start-up, and these will be allocated by the system's memory manager - so it is dynamic in the system-wide sense, but static at the process level.  In a standalone environment (typically an embedded system with no OS), the memory is essentially allocated at build time by the linker from a pool determined by the link map configuration.

Answer (score 2):

> For this they should be stored somewhere but in c it seems that an
>   array only takes 10^6 elements.

Not at all. I think you're allocating the array in a wrong way. Just writing

```
int myarray[big_number];
```

won't work, as it will try to allocate memory on the [stack](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/), which is very limited (several MB in size, often, so 10^6 is a good rule of thumb). A better way is to dynamically allocate:

```
int* myarray;

int main() {
  // Allocate the memory
  myarray = malloc(big_number * sizeof(int));
  if (!myarray) {
    printf("Not enough space\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // ...

  // Free the allocated memory
  free(myarray);

  return 0;
}
```

This will allocate the memory (or, more precise, `big_number * 4` bytes on a 32-bit machine) on the [heap](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/). Note: This might fail, too, but is mainly limited by the amount of free RAM which is much closer to or even above 10^9 (1 GB).

Answer (score -1):

An array uses a contiguous memory space. Therefore, if your memory is fragmented, you won't be able to use such array. Use a different data structure, like a linked list.

**About linked lists:**

- Wikipedia definition - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list
- Implementation in C - http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html

On a side note, I tried on my computer, and while I can't create an `int[1000000]`, a `malloc(1000000*sizeof(int))` works.

Comment: I don't think that is true. The operating system will allocate the memory non-contiguously and make it look like its contiguous